# the contact list length from graph contacts api does not match with the the contacts count shown by the people page of office365

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are using the graph api to fetch the contacts. But for a special test account the result from the `Graph API` does not match with what shown by the `people panel of the Office365`.
[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivflp.png)

Also, we do import the contact list **twice** by running script which resulting in duplicated contacts data which do have different `id` field. And we cannot find the duplicated ones from the `people panel of the Office365`.

So how can we get the same result shown as the screen shot which contact count is 5517.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want find the duplicated ones. There are may not have a API to do this.If you want to find the duplicate list of the contact, we can submit a feature in [the MS User Voice](https://office365.uservoice.com/).

And I have an another solution to do this by coding. The simple code as below:

```
var contacts = await _serviceClient.Me.Contacts.Request().GetAsync();
        // Get duplicate list of contacts through the name of the contact person
        var result = from contact in contacts.CurrentPage
                     group contact by contact.DisplayName into dupContacts
                     where dupContacts.Count() > 1
                     select dupContacts;
```

If you want distinct the contacts by using code, We can use the following code:

```
var contacts = await _serviceClient.Me.Contacts.Request().GetAsync();
var result = contacts.CurrentPage.Distinct(new ContactComparer())
```

And the `ContactComparer` class like this:

```
public class ContactComparer : IEqualityComparer<Contact>
{
    public bool Equals(Contact x, Contact y)
    {
        if (string.CompareOrdinal(x.DisplayName, y.DisplayName) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried this solution before, the filtered list's length still doesn't match with what shown by the outlook home page. 10 contacts short actually.

BTW, I also tried to filtered by the emailAddresses, still doesn't match.

Comment: As my understand, if you import the contact list twice, the property of `displayName` or other property should be double, and you can use the first solution to filter them.

Comment: Yes, but my real question is how the O365 decide which one is duplicated so they can show only 5517 contacts other than 6586. I want a generic solution for the question.

Comment: If so, you can submit an issue on [the github issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues) for more helper

Comment: Thank you for your help